# In JavaScript can you create a ref to an import with a string and variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I import a string like this:

```
import { ROUTE_TEXTS } from '../constants/routes';
```

How can in then later dynamically reference ROUTE_TEXTS? In my example here there is only one import but there could be many. I want the route property of an object to equal the imported routes. I tried this, but it didn't work - although it does for the object keys:

```
{
     route: ['ROUTE_' + someDynamicVar]
}
```

Is this possible without using eval()?

Comment: Please show the export of `ROUTE_TEXTS` in `../constants/routes`.

Comment: Your `import` statement only imports a single property, creating a single variable. If you want to be able to create the symbol dynamically, don't destructure and import the whole object so that you can construct a property name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't import the binding individually, just import the namespace object of the module.

```
import * as routes from '../constants/routes';
```

so that you can later do

```
const route = routes['ROUTE_' + someDynamicVar];
```

Comment: Note to self: First, engage brain. *Then* answer question.